# How to get user's followers and user's following user on the new Spotify Web api?

Tags: javascript, spotify, asp.net-web-api

After looking up about the `Spotify` new API docs, i'm asking to you guys about user's followers and user's following. How can we get this data on the new `Spotify` Web api ?

I want to send request to some endpoints urls like this below:

```
/v1/users/{user_id}/followers
```

and

```
/v1/users/{user_id}/followings
```

Did that is actually possible ?

Answer (score 5):

This is currently not possible. However, we'll be expanding the features in the Web API continuously, so please stay tuned for news on our [Developer site](http://developer.spotify.com/), and more specifically, the [Endpoint reference page](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/endpoint-reference/).

Edit: This feature request has been added to the [Web API's issue tracker](https://github.com/spotify/web-api/issues/4).

Comment: Any update on this topic yet? Will it be implemented?

Comment: @Roland, It's not implemented yet. ([Change log](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/change-log/)) Don't count on this feature being available in the short term.

Comment: Thanks for getting back so soon. I will look for another way to achieve my goal.

Comment: No problem. What's your use case?

Comment: I'm trying to do user recommendations based on semi-matching playlists.

Comment: [Playlist search](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/search-item/) might come in handy if you're looking for similar playlists.

Comment: @Michael Thelin

bump!   yes, this functionality is sorely needed -- is there any updates?!

Comment: No update regarding this I'm afraid. It's being tracked in this feature request, https://github.com/spotify/web-api/issues/4.

Comment: It's nearly end of 2016 and they still didn't bring this feature. My solution  is assuming the user is logged on via Facebook account and it's profile is public. With this way, you can fetch users friends via Selenium(any kind of browser which you can use on development) and check if they have any Spotify account. If they would have, then you can access their Spotify profile with their username.